# Convert nested list to a dataframe using Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I have the below nested list:

```
lisA = [['Monday', ['Cherry', 'Mango']],
 ['Tuesday', ['Blueberry', 'Apple', 'Grape']],
 ['Wednesday', ['Apple', 'Orange']],
 ['Thursday', ['Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Apple']],
 ['Friday', ['Orange', 'Cherry']]]
```

I need to convert this nested list to a dataframe which looks like the below:

```
| Day       | Item           |
| --------  | -------------- |
| Monday    | Cherry         |
| Monday    | Mango          |
|Tuesday    | Blueberry      |
|Tuesday    | Apple          |
|Tuesday    | Grape          |
|Wednesday  | Apple          |
|Wednesday  | Orange         |
|Thursday   | Watermelon     |
|Thursday   | Kiwi           |
|Thursday   | Apple          |
|Friday     | Orange         |
|Friday     | Cherry         |
```

If I use the below code to convert the nested list to a dataframe, I get Monday in one column and the entire Monday list in another column

```
pd.DataFrame(lisA)
```

What is the best way to convert the nested list (lisA) to a dataframe shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```py
df = (pd.DataFrame(lisA, columns=['Day', 'Item'])
      .explode('Item', ignore_index=True))
```

```
print(df)

          Day        Item
0      Monday      Cherry
1      Monday       Mango
2     Tuesday   Blueberry
3     Tuesday       Apple
4     Tuesday       Grape
5   Wednesday       Apple
6   Wednesday      Orange
7    Thursday  Watermelon
8    Thursday        Kiwi
9    Thursday       Apple
10     Friday      Orange
11     Friday      Cherry
```

Comment: if I have two nested list called `entry`, `exit`. How to add two nested list into dataframe.
I tried `df = (pd.DataFrame(entry,exit, columns=['Buy Date', 'Buy Entry','Buy Exit Date', 'Buy Exit']).explode('Buy Entry','Buy Exit', ignore_index=True))`   

But getting Error: `ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns`

How to solve this

Comment: @Divyank Don't know the structure of your `entry` and `exit`, you can ask a new question.